# design Optimized query in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

I am struggling alot in improving performance for rest api in rails. Currently, rest API takes 10 second for fetching 25000 records in which each record is 1 kb of size.

I am trying really hard to reduce it alot all by optimizing query, applying indexing etc. But nothing is working for now. I am new to database thing to might missing some silly point. I want to reduce the time to 1-2 seconds.

Here is my schema file to give idea of by database structure

```
 create_table "records", force: true do |t|
t.datetime "start"
t.datetime "end"
t.datetime "current"
t.integer  "user_id"
t.integer  "device_id"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
end

add_index "records", ["device_id"], name: "index_records_on_device_id", using: :btree
add_index "records", ["user_id"], name: "index_records_on_user_id", using: :btree

create_table "record_student", force: true do |t|
 t.string   "class_id"
t.string   "c_admin"
t.string   "Branch"
t.integer  "system_id"
t.integer  "asu"
t.decimal  "d_code",       precision: 10, scale: 0
t.integer  "c_code"
t.integer  "marks"
t.string   "stype"
t.integer  "record_id"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
 end

 add_index "record_student", ["record_id"], name: "index_record_student_on_record_id", using: :btree

create_table "record_emp", force: true do |t|
 t.string   "class_id"
t.string   "c_admin"
t.string   "Dept_name"
t.integer  "temp_id"
t.integer  "system_id"
t.integer  "asu"
t.decimal  "d_code",       precision: 10, scale: 0
t.integer  "c_code"
t.integer  "marks"
t.string   "stype"
t.integer  "record_id"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
 end

 add_index "record_emp", ["record_id"], name: "index_record_emp_on_record_id", using: :btree

create_table "record_other", force: true do |t|
t.integer  "d_code"
t.integer  "c_code"
t.integer  "code"
t.decimal  "marks",            precision: 10, scale: 0
t.string   "stype"
t.integer  "record_id"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

This is snippet but pretty much similar to main schema.

I am using this query to access records and it take

```
Records.owned_by(User.find_by_email(params[:user].to_s).id).where(device_id: params[:did]).includes(:record_students, :record_employees, :record_admins, :record_others)
```

results are `Completed 200 OK in 8713ms (Views: 4.8ms | ActiveRecord: 827.8ms)`

I just do not figure out why it is taking so much time, any suggestion to improve anything query or any other points

THanks

Answer (score 1):

With 25000 results in one query it will be an overkill for every server. Before trying to simplify the query, you should think about your solution. Here are a few suggestions:

- Add pagination to your results, so you don't need to query all records in database and map them to objects in ActiveRecord
- Check you are not dealing with N+1 Queries, look at [bullet](https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet) for clues
- Simplify your queries: Sometimes having only one complex query won't help in performance issues
- Select only the fields you need, take a look at [pluck method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-pluck)